# MVC hosted service checking database every few hours... (C#)

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller, service

I've been searching around for 3-4 days already and haven't found anything to help me find the best way to solve this problem.

So I am working on MVC Application, one of the possibilities is that users can order some digital material, pay for it and then choose the date when that material will be delivered (as a gift to a friend, etc...) via email with some link, the only problem is that for service to be running non-stop checking database every 5hours let's say.
I can't find a way to do that...

Comment: Are you using .net Core or .net 5? If so have a look at this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio or https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.8 to be exact. I just run into a hangfire lets see if I can make it work that way...

Comment: ... I think it will be hard... By default asp.net MVC does not really support a long running processes.... Attempts to do so will be hacky... Even if you use hangfire...

Comment: Yes, I agree I just read the doc on hangfire so it will be hacky and most likely impossible to do it the way I want. not sure if it's possible to do some kind of scheduled jobs different way...?

Comment: Well... It is possible... With .net 5 / .net core you almost get it for free. Basically there are 2 options 1) use a external program (this can be a custom build service/script performing the action or a scheduled task calling a https endpoint). 2) use a selfhosted MVC setup - which wraps your asp.net mvc application in an exe. But the latter will be a lot of work. I advise to create a PowerShell script call an endpoint scheduled by a task scheduler. You should be able to set it up rather quickly.

Comment: Try some methods with timing capabilities, such as BAT scripts, database jobs, and so on.